# Can you read a .txt file without importing or using any Java standard library packages or components?

Tags: java

One of the requirements in my homework assignment is to read integers from a *.txt file. However, we are not allowed to import or use any Java standard library packages or components. How would this be accomplished since we can't use Scanner, File, or others that help with IO? Thanks!

> Homework Objective: After completing the homework, the student should
> be able to
>
> - Implement a merge sort algorithm using recursion
> - Implement a quick sort algorithm using recursion
>
> You are given the following text files:
> `MyList.txt`
>
> 1. ) You must implement a recursive Quicksort algorithm that will read integers from the attached `MyList.txt` file. Your algorithm must sort
>    the list (integers) in ascending order.
> 2. You must implement a recursive Mergesort algorithm that will read integers from the attached `MyList.txt` file. Your algorithm must sort
>    the list (integers) in ascending order.
> 3. ScreenShots.doc or ScreenShots.pdf This file should contain screenshots of your output for both the programs.
>
> You are not allowed to import or use any Java standard library
> packages or components in your .java files.

Comment: What class is this? Why are they asking you to do that?

Comment: This is a Data Structures and Algorithms and I'm not sure? @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica

Comment: That's a bizarre requirement -  I'm not sure what their point in assigning that is, especially for a DSA class. What have you been covering lately?

Comment: Just basic sorting algorithms (insertion, bubble, merge, etc.) and calculating time complexities using the recursive tree and Master Theorem. But nothing about not using Scanner? @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the exact requirements, there's no way your professor would give you an assignment like this, unless it's a lesson in unavoidable failure.

Comment: @JonnyHenly sorry for the formatting because I don't have enough reputation to post images. But I copied/pasted the requirements with the circumstances of not being allowed to import or use any Java standard library packages.

Comment: You could maybe use JNI, I guess...  This is a really strange requirement, even by the standards of homework problems.

Comment: I don't think your professor realized what they were stipulating when they said *"You are not allowed to import or use any Java standard library packages or components in your .java files."* Rolling your own low level file IO classes and everything that comes with that is well beyond the scope of a DSA class, especially when the assignment focuses heavily on sorting. I would email them and get more clarity.

Comment: You could read the text file into your java editor so that you could have int[] a = {1, 2, 3...}. This is a bad idea, but it does fit with all the requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say that there is a mistake in the requirements for your assignment.

While it is possible to do I/O without using any standard Java I/O library packages, it involves writing C or C++ code methods to do I/O and accessing them via JNI or JNA.  I cannot imagine that that is what your teacher wants you to do ... in an exercise on sorting algorithms.

I expect that what your teacher actually *means* is that your implementations of QuickSort and MergeSort should not use any library packages.

But seriously, if you want clarification of the requirements for your homework, the only people who can actually do that are your teacher and their assistants.